# ScrollView bug when targeting Google API running on emulator devices

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm having a hard time debugging my app and I can't find anything wrong with it. This app have been running fine on the other or lower target framework.

The issue is, whenever I try to scroll a bit on any `View` that has a `ScrollView` attached in it, it starts to scroll to the bottom-most part and when I try to scroll it up, there was like a gravity that pulls it down, retaining the view from the bottom part of the layout.

I tested the 2 application currently I'm working with, on at least 3 different virtual devices that have these common specs:

```
CPU: Intel Atom (x86)
Target: Google APIs (x86 System Image) (API level 19)
Skin: HVGA
```

I also tested a very simple app that uses a `ScrollView` filled with `TextView`s on it, so that I can test a scrolling effect, but then again, the bug still occurs.

The reason why I want to use the Google APIs is for the **Google maps** in w/c it has also a `ScrollView` in w/c the bug can still be recognize.

**Update:** I tested some of the default apps installed in the emulator w/c runs under Google APIs framework and all of the scrollviews are buggy.

Comment: You can always test your app on real devices, I always feel the emulator slow and full of bugs.

Comment: @westlinkin Sadly, I can't afford one :(

Comment: You said you tested with a ScrollView filled with TextView, you should set both components' height WRAP_CONTENT and TextView.setText() set a long paragraph of text.

Comment: @westlinkin ScrollView's width= MATCH_PARENT, height=WRAP_CONTENT, while TextView's size is the same as scroll view and has a text like "Hello 1"... And this has nothing to do with it I think because the same happens on Google Maps.